# Desbordamiento de líneas al crear una longtable

Tags: latex

Actualmente estoy trabajando en apunte relacionado con Transformadas de Laplace para el cual dentro de mi proyecto de LaTeX necesito insertar una tabla con datos, en este caso utilicé una longtable. El problema ocurre que al momento de crear la tabla se desbordan algunas lineas de la misma, tal como se muestra marcado en rojo en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Tabla problemática]

Agradecería si me pueden guiar para deshacerme de estas líneas. A continuación, adjunto el código fuente principal del proyecto (acá están definidos los paquetes que importé y cómo esta organizado el proyecto mismo):

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
% paquetes
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref,theoremref}
\usepackage{comment}
% agregar tablas personalizadas
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{tabletitle}{RGB}{214, 214, 214}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{showframe} % visualizar area de escritura y margenes
%\usepackage{blindtext}

% proporciones del documento
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{headsep=1cm, footskip=28pt, margin=0.85in, bmargin=4cm}
% encabezado personalizado
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{52pt}
% formato de encabezado
\fancyhf{}
\lhead[\leftmark]{\thepage}
\rhead[\thepage]{\leftmark}
% disposición texto y párrafos
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % modificar sangria
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15} % modificar interlineado

\title{Prueba Paginación}
\author{Felipe Gutiérrez}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
% incluir las demás paginas del documento
\tableofcontents
\include{capitulo1.tex}

\end{document}
```

Y el código fuente de `capitulo1.tex` que es donde está la tabla con el problema en cuestión:

```
\section{section 1}
tabla de ejemplo

\begin{longtable}{|m{0.22\linewidth}|m{0.68\linewidth}|}
\label{tab:tab_transformada_laplace} \\
\hline
\cellcolor{tabletitle} Función & \cellcolor{tabletitle} Transformada\\
\hline
$$f(t)$$ & $$F(s)$$\\
$$\alpha f(t)\pm\beta g(t)$$ & $$\alpha F(s)\pm\beta G(s)$$\\
$$f'(t)$$ & $$sF(s)-f(0)$$\\
$$f''(t)$$ & $$s^2F(s)-sf(0)-f'(0)$$\\
$$f^{(n)}(t)$$ & $$s^nF(s)-s^{n-1}f(0)-s^{n-2}f'(0)-\cdots-f^{(n-1)}(0)$$\\
$$\int^{t}_0 f(t)\:dt$$ & $$\frac{F(s)}{s}$$\\
$$(f\cdot g)(t)$$ & $$F(s)\cdot G(s)$$\\
$$e^{\alpha t}$$ & $$\frac{1}{s-\alpha}; s>\alpha$$\\
$$\sin{(\beta t)}$$ & $$\frac{\beta}{s^2+\beta^2}; s>0$$\\
$$\cos{(\beta t)}$$ & $$\frac{s}{s^2+\beta^2}; s>0$$\\
$$\sinh{(\beta t)}$$ & $$\frac{\beta}{s^2-\beta^2}; s>0$$\\
$$\cosh{(\beta t)}$$ & $$\frac{s}{s^2-\beta^2}; s>0$$\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\chapter*{New Chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{New Chapter}
sample text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes una `\label{}` al principio que es la que causa la aparición de una "fila extra", que a su vez causa esas líneas verticales.

El comando `\label{}` debe usarse después de `\caption{}` y en tu caso falta este último. Una forma por tanto de arreglar el problema es:

```latex
\begin{longtable}{|m{0.22\linewidth}|m{0.68\linewidth}|}
\caption{Tabla de prueba}\label{tab:tab_transformada_laplace}\\
\hline
\cellcolor{tabletitle} Función & \cellcolor{tabletitle} Transformada\\
\hline
$$f(t)$$ & $$F(s)$$\\
$$\alpha f(t)\pm\beta g(t)$$ & $$\alpha F(s)\pm\beta G(s)$$\\
$$f'(t)$$ & $$sF(s)-f(0)$$\\
$$f''(t)$$ & $$s^2F(s)-sf(0)-f'(0)$$\\
$$f^{(n)}(t)$$ & $$s^nF(s)-s^{n-1}f(0)-s^{n-2}f'(0)-\cdots-f^{(n-1)}(0)$$\\
$$\int^{t}_0 f(t)\:dt$$ & $$\frac{F(s)}{s}$$\\
$$(f\cdot g)(t)$$ & $$F(s)\cdot G(s)$$\\
$$e^{\alpha t}$$ & $$\frac{1}{s-\alpha}; s>\alpha$$\\
$$\sin{(\beta t)}$$ & $$\frac{\beta}{s^2+\beta^2}; s>0$$\\
$$\cos{(\beta t)}$$ & $$\frac{s}{s^2+\beta^2}; s>0$$\\
$$\sinh{(\beta t)}$$ & $$\frac{\beta}{s^2-\beta^2}; s>0$$\\
$$\cosh{(\beta t)}$$ & $$\frac{s}{s^2-\beta^2}; s>0$$\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

que produce este resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Si no quieres una caption, entonces tampoco necesitas una label. Puedes eliminarla (junto con el `\\` al final de esa línea) y el problema también desaparecerá.